# When I attempt to measure Vbc for the circuit below, the LED partially illuminates when the switch is open. Can someone explain why please?

Tags: transistors, voltage-measurement

When I measure Vb relative to ground I get a value of 0.00V and with Vc relative to ground I get a value of 7.15V when the circuit is open. Subtracting Vc from Vb I obtain -7.15V for Vbc which is expected because the transistor should be in cut-off mode (I think, because I am very new to electronics and self-taught). However, when I attempt to measure Vbc directly by carefully attaching the red probe of my multimeter to the base and the black probe to the collector (when the switch is open), I get a reading of -6.21V and the LED partially illuminates. Could someone explain why there is a difference in values and why the LED partially illuminates please when the switch is open? Also, this might be a bit much to ask but could you please remember that I'm new to all this and so could you please answer as user-friendly as possible - i.e a sort of transistors for beginners level. Thanking you in anticipation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRIny4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 9):

Your circuit is a very sensitive one, especially when the human eye is added into the picture. Even very small leakage currents can produce a noticeable effect.

Some voltmeters have very low impedance to them. Some, much higher. I'll discuss analog meters first as a segue towards concluding about how a good quality digital meter performs, as well. Then I'll talk about how to achieve such a measurement, if you really want to go the extra mile to do so.

First up is:

### Analog meters

For analog ones, you can look at the lowest current scale to get an idea. Cheap ones will be around \$200\:\mu\text{A}\$, full scale. Slightly better ones will be around \$50\:\mu\text{A}\$, full scale. Really good ones will be \$5\:\mu\text{A}\$, full scale. And anything still better than that is a delicate keep-sake.

If you are using a cheap analog voltmeter with its lowest current scale being \$200\:\mu\text{A}\$, then you can work out what the loading is likely to be. Choosing a DC scale for a max of \$20\:\text{V}\$ means \$\frac{20\:\text{V}}{200\:\mu\text{A}}=100\:\text{k}\Omega\$. That's what the loading is likely to be.

Let's do a quick calculation. The collector current is what we care about here. In your circuit, the collector voltage will be \$9\:\text{V}\$ less the green LED voltage drop (about \$2.5\:\text{V}\$) and less the \$470\:\Omega\$ resistor drop. So we can write this out as \$V_{_\text{C}}=9\:\text{V}-2.5\:\text{V}-I_{_\text{C}}\cdot 470\:\Omega\$. That's one equation.

But we also know that the voltmeter (as I've specified it so far) presents a \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ between the collector and base. And we can guess that the base will be between \$600\:\text{mV}\$ and \$700\:\text{mV}\$, if the BJT is active enough. So the base current can be worked out from this and by applying \$\beta\approx 300\$ to that, find that \$I_{_\text{C}}\approx \beta\cdot \frac{V_{_\text{C}}-650\:\text{mV}}{100\:\text{k}\Omega}\$ or \$V_{_\text{C}}=650\:\text{mV}+100\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot\frac{I_{_\text{C}}}{\beta}\$. That's another equation.

So, just setting these two as equal to each other,

$$9\:\text{V}-2.5\:\text{V}-I_{_\text{C}}\cdot 470\:\Omega=650\:\text{mV}+100\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot\frac{I_{_\text{C}}}{\beta}$$

Or, \$I_{_\text{C}}\approx 7.3\:\text{mA}\$. That's definitely enough to activate the green LED, making it plainly visible. This also greatly alters what you would measure with this analog voltmeter in that particular range setting.

Even a good quality \$50\:\mu\text{A}\$ movement analog meter will cause \$I_{_\text{C}}\approx 3.2\:\text{mA}\$ and an unusually superior \$5\:\mu\text{A}\$ movement analog meter will cause \$I_{_\text{C}}\approx 420\:\mu\text{A}\$. (This last is approaching a good quality digital meter, though!)

Next up:

### Digital meters

The quality varies here, as well. But let's look at a decent (if old) meter from Tektronix, the [DMM916](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/TektronixDMM916UserManual.3345434866/view). This one presents about \$10\:\text{M}\Omega\$. Plugging that into the above equation we can find that \$I_{_\text{C}}\approx 175\:\mu\text{A}\$. That's more than an order of magnitude less than the cheap analog meter, but given that our vision has to be sensitive over many orders of magnitude and that this is a green LED which sits near our peak visual sensitivity, as well, I would not find it surprising that you might also see it even in this case.

Finally:

### How to measure it

If you want to make measurements like this, then you need an input that is closer to \$1\:\text{G}\Omega\$, or beyond. To get there, you will need the aid of an opamp.

This can be handled by some specialty devices such as the now-ancient [Renesas CA3130](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/ca3130-ca3130a-datasheet), first released back in 1974, and which isn't particularly precise and can be more of a noise generator if not careful, or perhaps the more modern [TI LMP7721](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmp7721.pdf?ts=1696704389082).

I found [this article](https://www.eeweb.com/high-impedance-dc-voltmeter-using-mos-op-amp/) discussing how you might use the CA3130, for example, as representative of the basic topology for such measurements.

You can also use nulling techniques. Some thoughts are presented near the bottom of [this article](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-8/voltmeter-impact-measured-circuit/).

But the main take-away is that you need a *delicate device* if you are intent on making such measurements, where even very tiny currents can impact your results.

Comment: There are some voltmeters designed for measuring very high-impedance sources, too. They're typically called "electrometers", and they're not cheap.

Comment: @Hearth Yeah. I suppose I could mention Keithley. (Or some useful Burr-Brown parts.) But I decided to avoid that.

Comment: @periblepsis. Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. However, the maths is fine but why is the first analogue equation Vc = 9 - 2.5 - Ic.470ohms i.e. are you applying KVL and if so where does Vc come from? I hope that this is not a stupid question. Thank you.

Comment: @JR \$V_{_\text{C}}\$ is the voltage at the collector. I often call the positive supply rail voltage something similar looking, \$V_{_\text{CC}}=9\:\text{V}\$. In any case, KVL tells you that the collector voltage will be the supply voltage, less the voltage drop across the collector resistor and across the LED. I just picked \$2.5\:\text{V}\$ since the LED is green and the drop across the collector resistor will be the LED current, which is also the collector current too, times the resistor value. That's where that equation comes from.

Answer (score 3):

> *However, when I attempt to measure Vbc directly by carefully attaching
> the red probe of my multimeter to the base and the black probe to the
> collector (when the switch is open), I get a reading of -6.21V and the
> LED partially illuminates. Could someone explain why there is a
> difference in values and why the LED partially illuminates please when
> the switch is open?*

If you put a 10 MΩ resistor in place of your meter your LED would also partially illuminate. Meters (usually) have an input impedance of 10 MΩ on DC voltage ranges and, this allows current from collector into the base. This means that the transistor is biased to conduct a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

When the button is not pushed, the transistor base is not connected anywhere and it is floating.

Any base current that gets coupled in any to the circuit will cause collector current to flow and LED to light up. It does not matter from where the current comes from or leaks to the base, it can come via multimeter, via your finger, or getting capacitively or inductively coupled to the base.

Just try making a phone call and put your phone (i.e. RF transmitter) near the transistor. LED will likely light up.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. To measure Vbc should I measure Vb relative to ground and Vc relative to ground when the circuit is open and then subtract Vc from Vb?

Comment: @JR If you want to measure Vbc then yes because the meter affects the circuit if you put it between Vb and Vc. However, other than measuring for kicks or for learning experience, why would you measure Vbc as in that circuit it's not useful to know it, Vb (Vbe) and Vc (Vce) are more useuful separately than Vbc. What would you do with Vbc?

Comment: It's really for learning experience and also to confirm that Vcb + Vbe = vC

Comment: It's really for learning experience and also to confirm that Vcb + Vbe = Vce experimentally, using my multimeter.  Also I am confirming which mode the transistor is in experimentally in each situation, i.e. open: it should be in cut-off mode & closed: it should be in saturation mode or active mode (in fact I think I've shown it's in saturation mode because Vce = 0.08V which is very close to the typical value from the datasheet  i.e. 0.09V. I really am learning from scratch. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score -2):

Going from your circuit diagram your emitter is going to ground so the transistor is truly doing nothing in that circuit. With where your battery is and that it is not stated what side is positive and what side is negative. We can guess one of two things from this.

One the battery is positive towards the diode.

Two the diode could be in backwards.

The transistor emits from pin 3 as per the datasheet. That is currently going to ground so what are you emitting?

The reason I can think of about the negative voltage you get there is the battery is pointing negative to the diode. And the diode is in backwards.

Diodes. And light emitting diodes only allow current to flow in one direction.

Also the current coming out of that transistor is 100-200mA that would be enough to turn that diode on with the dmm. Provided there is power of positive going to the diode.

The transistor could be faulty to that is a possibility and some how could be switched gates of the pins.

The flat side of the transistor is from left to right pin 1 2 3.

Not sure if this helps but hope it enlightens you